# How do i regex coefficient of cubic equation?

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a cubic equation  `-2x^3-18x^2-12x+112=0` . I want to regex out the coefficients of the equation ..so that i am left with...

```
a=-2
b=-18
c=-12
d=112
```

All equations are in the form of ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0 .

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the coefficient are integers, you can do:

```
s = '-2x^3-18x^2-12x+112=0'

import re

a, b, c, d = map(int, re.findall(r'(?<!\^|=)([\d-]+)', s))

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
-2
-18
-12
112
```

Comment: Yes..all coefficients are integers only.